# Tcp Connection - React Native Windows

Tags: react-native, tcpclient, react-native-windows

I have used react-native-tcp-socket for react native apps. I was working on a react native windows app and I tried to use react-native-tcp-socket but it was not possible to establish the connection to the server. Do you guys have any experience with TCP connection on react native windows app?

My code:

```
``const client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options, () => {
        client.write("Hello server!");
        client.destroy();
      });
      client.on("data", function (data) {
        response = data;
      });`your text`
      client.on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      client.on("close", function () {
        console.log("Connection closed!");
      });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.